# Trying to get my Ralink RT3070L to work on my 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, 18.04, ralink

Anyone have a driver that might actually work?

I saw some links in other threads but they were dead.
I am pretty green on compiling and such (it does not want to work compiling the 2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO.bz2)and this simply does seem beyond me at the moment.

I would really appreciate any assistance anyone can offer in here.
I am running Lubuntu on an Asus laptop.

Comment: That seems to be a tough one. I found a slightly newer (2012) tarball driver, but still you would need to do `.configure, ` `make` and `sudo make install`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961439/why-always-configure-make-make-install-as-3-separate-steps). No idea if that will work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Where is this tarball driver?

Comment: I found it here: https://d86o2zu8ugzlg.cloudfront.net/mediatek-craft/drivers/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2

Comment: scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/User1/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/User1/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/User1/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/User1/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic'
Makefile:388: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you there. I'm no good at compiling things.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. Hopefully someone will be able to help. If you know anyone feel free to send them this way. I am willing to troubleshoot this terminal line by line if necessary. If it have to be moved to chat by virtue of being lengthy and thorough, so be it.